# Mouseover - make image appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image appear when I mouse over a certain image map and also still have my other mouseover and mouseout functions working.

I'm using : http://clba.nl/sitepoint/img-hover-demo-js2.htm

Which is basically.

```
<style>
  #img2{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
  }
</style>
```

```
<script>
  var img1 = document.getElementById("img1"),
      img2 = document.getElementById("img2");

  img2.style.display = "none"; // hide when page is loaded 

  img1.onmouseover = function(){
    img2.style.display = "block";
  }

  img1.onmouseout = function(){
    img2.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

I'm using it now on a website using this method. But instead of `<img id="img1" src="images/van4.jpg" alt="" />` I'm using an ID inside my map area. Like this

```
<map name="map12" id="img_id12">
    <area id="img2" class="youtube" coords="3878,24,3957,96" shape="rect" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/skV-q5KjrUA" style="outline:none;"     
        onmouseover="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/text/day/12solaire-ani.gif'; PlaySound('solaire'); "
        onmouseout="if(document.images) document.getElementById('img_id12').src= 'assets/images/no-text/day/12.gif'; StopSound('solaire'); PlaySound('solaire-stop');"  />
</map>
```

This result is my image showing up when I hover over image map. However, it cancels out my other functions. Any tip how to make everything work together?

Comment: i didn't see any other function apart from  onmouseover and onmouseout. what else it is canceling ?

Comment: Please provide full code then i will check it

Answer (score 0):

You're best off using the CSS :hover pseudo class to make img2 appear.

Get rid of img1.onmouseover and img1.onmouseout, and add the following css in your style block:

```
#img1:hover + #img2 {display:block}
```

I've created an example fiddle here... https://jsfiddle.net/clayRav/6kvw3ujk/.

Comment: What happened @StephanieHallberg? 
Are the images generated programmatically, is that why the style sheet approach won't work?
Can you create a JSFiddle with your code? Did you have a look at my fiddle?